Pure death process
I came across this exercise that I can't solve:

Let us consider a pure death process $X(t)$ with $\mu_n=\mu,\ n>0$. Define the process $Y(t)$ such that $Y(t)=k-X(t)$, with $k=X(0)$.

Find $\mathbb P(Y(t)=n), \quad n =0,1,\dots$
Let $N$ be a Poisson random variable of mean $\lambda$ and $Z(t)=N-X(t)$. Find $\mathbb P(Z(t)=n), \quad n =0,1,\dots$


I think I have solved the first part considering the fact that the death of a pure death process occur as a Poisson process. Therefore:
\begin{align*}
   \mathbb P(Y(t)=n) & = \mathbb P(k-X(t)=n) = \\
   & = \mathbb P(X(t)=k-n) = \\
   & = P_{k,k-n}(t) = \begin{cases}
    e^{-\theta t}\frac{(\theta t)^{n}}{n!}, \qquad & n=0,\dots,k-1 \\
    \sum_{i=k}^{+\infty} e^{-\theta t}\frac{(\theta t)^{i}}{(i)!} & n=k
   \end{cases}
  \end{align*}
and $\mathbb P(Y(t)=n)=0$ for $n>k$.
However, I'm not sure if this is correct and I can't solve the second part.
